# AngularJS ng-repeat doesn't work on Django powered webpage

Tags: javascript, angularjs

I have this 2 parts of AngularJS codes in my Django powered webpage.

**Part1**

```
<div class="categoryList">
        <ul>
            <li data-ng-repeat="cat in categories"> 
                <a>{$ cat.name $}</a>
            </li>
        </ul>
</div>
```

**Part 2**

```
<li data-ng-repeat="i in range(pictures[currentCat].length)">
    <a data-ng-click="changePage(i)">{$ i $}</a>            
</li>
```

This is my controller

```
$scope.currentPage = 1;
$scope.currentCat = 0;

$.getJSON('categories/', 
 function(data) {
    $scope.categories= data;
});
$scope.pictures=[cat1,cat2,cat3,cat4,cat5]; //cat1..cat5 are some dictionaries like 'categories'

$scope.changePage = function(i){
        $scope.currentPage=i;
    };
```

The problem is part 2 works fine while loading the page, But part1 doesn't work until I click on a page number from part2 list and run 'changePage'

This was working fine when my webpage wasn't powered by Django

**Update**

views.py

```
def getcategories(request): // /categories/ url runs this 
    dictionaries = [obj.as_json() for obj in Category.objects.all()]
    return HttpResponse(json.dumps(dictionaries), content_type='application/json')
```

models.py

```
class Category(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField(default='other',max_length=50)
    upload_date = models.DateTimeField(default=datetime.now, blank=True)

    def as_json(self):
        return {
            "id": self.id,
            "name": self.name
        }
```

Comment: Try adding another braclet to the output like `{{cat.name}}`

Comment: Did it solve your problem? In that case I will post it as a solution and you can mark it as solved :)

Comment: @simpe well it did. But it doesn't work on my actual code which is getting `categories` from django model as a json (check my edit on controller part)

Comment: Is that perhaps suitable for another question then? Shall I post my answer or not, do you think? You should use Angular's `$http.get()` to get the information.

Comment: @simpe since I changed my question, maybe another hint is needed

Comment: I posted an answer. Try not mixing jQuery with Angular. Try using `$http.get` and you can send a header with `Content-type: application/json`.

Comment: @simpe I used `$http.get` But it doesn't work at all

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/67865/discussion-between-simpe-and-alex-jolig).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I added `$scope.$apply()` to `$.getJSON` and now it updates `$scope.categories` as soon as it gets the results. and everything is working fine now.

```
$.getJSON('categories/', 
 function(data) {
    $scope.categories= data;
    $scope.$apply();
});
```

Answer (score 0):

As simpe says the output should be `{{cat.name}}` and `{{i}}`.

About the "categories", check that the url is working, and then using your browser developer tools see that the right url is invoked.

Also you can use [django rest framework](http://www.django-rest-framework.org/) and [$resource](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ngResource/service/$resource) to send your data between front-end and back-end.

Comment: I changed my AngularJS template tags to `{$ $}` so it doesn't get conflict with Django's. Also I checked my categories url and it returns just the Json i need in the browser. But no `$.getJSON` nor `$http.get` returns that Json Until I run `changePage` by clicking on second ng-repeat list `<a>` tags

Comment: try using break points in your controller and see if the code is executed, or where is stoping

Comment: Also if you have a problem in the .html some times its stop executing the javascript. So maybe there is a problem with `currentPage` when it loads.